# AWS DynamoDB scan FilterExpression use not equals on String in list

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a List with ID's of type String. I want to scan DynamoDB and get a result list with items that do NOT have these ID's. But I can not figure out how to type the filter expression. ReviewId is the primary partition key of type String.

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<>();
eav.put(":idFilter", new AttributeValue().withSS(idFilter));

DynamoDBScanExpression scanExp = new DynamoDBScanExpression()
          .withFilterExpression("ReviewId <> (:idFilter)")
          .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
```

The above filter expression is valid but it still always returns items with id's in the list.
I have also tried to include the word `in` before and after the `<>` operator.

Comment: ReviewId attribute is of DynamoDB data type SET or LIST ?

Comment: @notionquest ReviewID is the primary partition key in the table it is of type String.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the filter expression as below and populate the `ExpressionAttributeValues` with values for keys `:reviewId1, :reviewId2, :reviewId3`.

```
FilterExpression: "NOT ReviewId in (:reviewId1, :reviewId2, :reviewId3)"
```

**Note:-**

Unfortunately, you can't keep the `idFilter` as SET or LIST to compare with String attribute of DynamoDB.

Comment: This is great info, why in the heck is it not documented on the AWS docs. Very annoying.